# Functionality of the operations that are common in different types

Tags: javascript

when I run this code in javascript and not understand, why the answer is 2:

```
“1”- -”1”
```

Comment: In math, when you subtract a negative number, you actually add its positive value. So `1 - -1 === 2` (and in JS, when using subtraction on Strings, they are cast to numbers automatically. With `+`, you would get `"1" + "1" === "11"` because it will simply concatenate them)

Comment: You mean this ``("1") - (-"1")`` ? Then it's just basic maths, there JavaScript is converting the string into numbers(integers) and then adding as two minus results in addtion.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript has two distinct operations denoted by the dash (`-`) symbol: subtraction, which is a binary operation, as in `1-2`, and the unary negation operation, as in `-5`. Both operations convert their arguments to Numbers, so your expression is interpreted as

```
Number("1") <subtract> (<negate> Number("1"))
```

which results in `1 - (-1)`, which is `2`.

Note that this contrasts with another "dual" operator `+`, which performs the Number conversion only in the unary form:

```
10 + +"1"  // 11
10 +  "1"  // "101"
```